How do I resize an "Array of T"?
Simplified code :
class procedure ArrayUtils.test<T>(var myArray: Array of T);
begin
  SetLength(myArray, 1);
end;

This leads to the error E2008 Incompatible types. Apparently SetLength isn't to be used with arrays defined like this, and I cannot use TArray<T> due to other design constraints. So how can I resize my array here ?
I'm not sure why the compiler refuses this, as when using a local Array of T it compiles perfectly fine ? I also tried removing the var, without luck.
Edit : Another thing I tried is doing myArray := myArray + [element];. Didn't work, same error.

You might be interested in this, too: https://github.com/WilliCommer/ArrayHelper

You cannot resize when using array of X in a method signature because it is not a dynamic array as one might think but a so-called open array parameter.
When you want to resize a dynamic array that is being passed in you need to work with TArray<T> or some other dynamic array type declaration.

What other declarations are there ?

Your parameter is not (a var reference to) a Dynamic Array, as you are expecting. It is actually an Open Array instead, and an Open Array cannot be resized.
Per the documentation:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters

Open Array Parameters
Open array parameters allow arrays of different sizes to be passed to the same procedure or function. To define a routine with an open array parameter, use the syntax array of type (rather than array[X..Y] of type) in the parameter declaration. For example:
function Find(A: array of Char): Integer;
declares a function called Find that takes a character array of any size and returns an integer.

Note: The syntax of open array parameters resembles that of dynamic array types, but they do not mean the same thing. The previous example creates a function that takes any array of Char elements, including (but not limited to) dynamic arrays. To declare parameters that must be dynamic arrays, you need to specify a type identifier:

type TDynamicCharArray = array of Char;
function Find(A: TDynamicCharArray): Integer;

Within the body of a routine, open array parameters are governed by the following rules:

...
They can be passed to other procedures and functions only as open array parameters or untyped var parameters. They cannot be passed to SetLength.
...


So, if you can't use System.TArray<T> then you will have to declare your own dynamic array type, eg:
type
  TMyArray<T> = array of T;

class procedure ArrayUtils.test<T>(var myArray: TMyArray<T>);

...

var anArrayOfInteger: TMyArray<Integer>;
ArrayUtils.test<Integer>(anArrayOfInteger); 

Alternatively, move T onto ArrayUtils itself instead of on test so that you can declare you array type as a member of ArrayUtils<T>, eg:
type
  ArrayUtils<T> = class
  public
    type TArrayOfT = array of T;
    class procedure test(var myArray: TArrayOfT);
  end;

... 

var anArrayOfInteger: ArrayUtils<Integer>.TArrayOfT;
ArrayUtils<Integer>.test(anArrayOfInteger);


Okay so the same signature actually means something different because it's an argument ? Good god.
The ArrayUtils solution looked great but the compiler doesn't like it.
ArrayUtils<Integer>.test(anArrayOfInteger); leads to the error "E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical"

@JohnJohn that is unfortunately the nature of a var parameter, the type of the parameter has to exactly match the type of the variable being passed in. I updated my examples to show this.
